# Return Value or Passing Pointer as Argument?

Tags: c

I learn that in order to access or modify the value of a variable by calling a function, we need to pass pointers as arguments such as below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

//create a function 
void Increment(int* x) {    
   *x = *x+1;
   printf("Address of variable x in increment = %p\n",x); 

}

int main() {
   int a;
   a = 10;
   Increment(&a);   
   printf("Address of variable 'a' in main = %p\n",&a);
   printf("Value of a in main function = %d\n",a); 


}
```

But I did another test, and I found out that by calling the function and returning the value, I can also achieve the same result.

```
#include <stdio.h>

//create a function 
int Increment(int x) {        // do not use VOID
   x = x+1;
   printf("Address of variable x in increment = %p\n",x); 
   return x;                  

}

int main() {
   int a;
   a = 10;
       int hasil;
       hasil = Increment(a);   
   printf("Address of variable 'a' in main = %p\n",&a);
   printf("Value of a in main function = %d\n",hasil); 


}
```

My questions :

1) Do I have to pass pointers as argument if I can just use return value to achieve the same result?

2) I observe when I print the address of the memory of variable 'x' from the function that returns value, the memory address is very short 0xb , any idea why? normally the address is very long.

Comment: What if you want to modify more than one variable? (Also they don't do the exact same thing - the second version copies the value of the variable)

Comment: Returning the function result means you can use it in expressions; a void function cannot be used in expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Do I have to pass pointers as argument if I can just use return value to achieve the same result?

No, you don't always have to. But observes that it frees up the return value of the function for error reporting. A very simple example:

```
enum error_code {
  E_SUCCESS,
  E_GENERAL_FAILURE,
  E_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED,
  E_INVALID_ARGUMENT,
  E_FILE_NOT_EXIST
};

struct my_important_data {
  // stuff
};

enum error_code fill_important_data_from_file(char const *file_name,
                                              struct my_important_data **data)
{
  if(!data || !file_name)
    return E_INVALID_ARGUMENT;

  *data = malloc(sizeof(**data));

  if(!*data)
    return E_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED;

  // Return different error codes based on type of failure
  // so the caller can know what exactly went wrong

  return E_SUCCESS;
}
```

> 2) I observe when I print the address of the memory of variable 'x' from the function that returns value, the memory address is very short 0xb , any idea why? normally the address is very long.

That's because you are using the `%p` conversion specifier to print a regular int, and not an actual address. Strictly speaking that's causing the `printf` function to have undefined behavior.

Comment: Could you please explain further what it means by 'frees up the return value of the function for error reporting'? and the as regard to %p, what should i use to print the actual address?

Comment: @LionGordon In C language, return values are generally used for status/error codes because there are no exceptions. So, it depends on your API design, how you want to treat your return value.

Comment: @LionGordon - you can print the address of `x` by taking it's address `(void*)&x`. As for an example, see my revised post.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok, I remember the void* now

Comment: @LionGordon - The `void*` on it's own isn't enough, you must use the addressof operator `&`

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, I understand.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass a pointer to a function when you need to modify the elements of an array. In C, you can't pass an array or return an array from a function.

Answer for your second question is, in C function argument are passed by value. That means the value of passed arguments is copied to parameters (which are local to the function) of the function. Therefore the address of passed argument and the address of function parameter are different.

Comment: Not to modify the elments of the array because the array is passed by reference anyway.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie; C only supports pass by value. No pass by reference.

Comment: Yes, Haccks, that means the compiler passes the address of the array "by value" and as a result, the array is "passed by reference". You need to pass a pointer to the array in e.g. `int *A; ... f(&A){*A=realloc(..`

Comment: @LionGordon; No. It's pass by pointer which ultimately is pass by reference.

Comment: @haccks I didn't downvote you, I don't know who did that :D

Answer (score -1):

If parameter `x` is passed by point or reference, then there is no value copy of `x` is created.
If not, there is a copy created. This is the difference.
Think about this situation, if the parameter is a complicate `struct test`, it is a waste of time to make a copy of `test`. 
And if you pass `x` by point, you can use it as input and also as output.

Comment: Please make your solution more clear; it is a bit difficult to understand as is.

Comment: @Charles I understand that but I'm asking why I should use pointers if I can achieve the same result by using return value