# Why are COM pointer arguments cast as void instead of IUnknown?

Tags: c++, pointers, winapi, com, iunknown

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I wasn't clear on why COM pointer arguments are typically cast as `(void**)` instead of `(IUnknown**)`. And then sometimes `IUnknown` pointers are in fact used, like with `IObjectWithSite::SetSite`. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: **TLDR**: Legacy. Because COM was also meant to work with C, not just C++.

Comment: @selbie if that's really your understanding of the reason, you should make it an answer.

Comment: The ability to declare polymorphic interface pointers only exists in C++.  The COM runtime api (CoCreateInstance et al) is a C api, and therefore requires a C type.  No choice but void*.  Actually programming OLE in C is drastically impractical, so using IUnknown* in interfaces like IObjectWithSite is practical.

Comment: @han: Mostly correct, but you are conflating `[in]` and `[out]` parameters. The latter require polymorphic interface pointers, so `void*` is the only option given a C ABI. In the former case, however, the interface *requires* an `IUnknown*`, not some polymorphic (in the language-level sense) interface pointer. This isn't about practicability. It's about correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "get-type" interface methods (like `IObjectWithSite::QueryInterface`, `IObjectWithSite::GetSite`, `IMoniker::BindToObject`, etc...), because it wouldn't change anything, you'd have to cast anyway, except when you do require an `IUnknown*` reference, but you already have it because ... you're using it (the `IUknown*` reference is always the same pointer per [COM rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)#remarks)).

`IObjectWithSite::SetSite` is a "set-type" method, so it makes more sense to give you an `IUnknown*` reference.

It's probably more arguable in some static methods like [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance) or [CoGetObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objbase/nf-objbase-cogetobject)  I think they could have put `IUnknown**` there instead of `void**` but then, they would have two different styles. And you wouldn't be able to use the old [IID_PPV_ARGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/com-coding-practices#the-iid_ppv_args-macro) macro that's so practical to use, and recommended as a coding practice to avoid type cast errors.

I suggest you get a copy of the authoritative "Essential COM" from Don Box, and read up to page 60 (at least :-).

Comment: *"you'd have to cast anyway"* - Except, you aren't allowed to cast in COM. If you need to move from one interface type to another, a call to `QueryInterface` is required. *"I think they could have put `IUnknown**` there instead of `void**`"* - That's wrong. It assumes that interface inheritance were always modeled using a language-level construct that implies a relationship between pointers to these interfaces. COM does not mandate this requirement, and a programming language like C certainly cannot implement this.

Comment: @IInspectable - I mean't you'd cast to void** anyway so QI compiles. And for the rest, you think what you want.

Comment: @IInspectable - sure, but what's the point? I could say "you'd have to cast in C++ anyway" if you like it more, but the question is about C++ (and COM has really its root in C++) and still, they could have used IUnknown* anyway. In fact, they sometimes did: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/objidl/nf-objidl-icallfactory-createcall

Comment: Being language-agnostic was one of COM's design goals. With that goal, the options for an ABI are limited to a single one in practice: C's. If anything, COM is rooted in C, certainly not in C++. Microsoft's C++ compiler decided to emit COM-compatible v-tables; i.e. Microsoft's C++ implementation followed COM rules, not the other way around. And you are still wrong: An out-parameter that can return *any* interface type, must return the interface pointer through a pointer to the *final* type. The fact that you discovered a buggy signature doesn't change that. Rationale can be found in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about out-parameters that "return" a value via a pointer, e.g.:

```
IUnknown *u;
QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void **)&u);

IDispatch *d;
QueryInterface(IID_IDispatch, (void **)&d);
```

Note: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42922582/return-value-or-passing-pointer-as-argument) if you are unfamiliar with the concept of using pass-by-pointer to "return" values.

---

The prototype of `QueryInterface` is:

```
HRESULT QueryInterface(REFIID iid, void **ptr);
```

The argument `&u` would have type `IUnknown **`  already (so there is no reason to cast it to the type it already is, as you seem to be suggesting). The cast is to change the type to the expected type for the function parameter.

In Standard C++ the code above is actually undefined behaviour (strict aliasing violation -- you can not pretend a pointer points to a different type object than it really does). The correct usage of this function is:

```
void *temp;
QueryInterface(IID_IFoo, &temp);
IFoo *foo = static_cast<IFoo *>(temp);
```

However the Microsoft compiler supports the version with the C-style cast. It makes the same changes to the memory location as if the interface pointer had been declared as `void *` instead of its real type.

---

Why does `QueryInterface` take `void **` and not `IUnknown **`? Well, that would be nice to avoid the cast if you are specifically requesting `IID_IUnknown`, however any other interface would require the C-style cast anyway. And it might cause confusion since (for other interfaces) the returned pointer is not necessarily a valid `IUnknown *` value .

In C++ programming you can (and perhaps should) use template wrapper classes that perform all the right type manipulations . The Windows API calls are compatible with C so they can not include strongly-typed generics .

NB. All calls to `QueryInterface` should check the return value,  I omitted that here for brevity.

Comment: There is actually a very important difference between ``void**`` and ``IUnknown**``, namely the type of cast required (in the line ``IFoo* foo = ...`` at the end). Using ``void**``, a ``static_cast`` or ``reinterpret_cast`` is sufficient, while using ``IUnknown**`` would either require a ``dynamic_cast`` (which would turn using QueryInterface quite useless), or the returend pointer would not be guaranteed to actually point to a valid ``IUnknown`` (especially if multiple and/or virtual inheritance is used in the object's implementation)

Comment: @Bizzarrus in both cases you have to use `reinterpret_cast` (and it is undefined behaviour in both cases anyway as covered in my answer). I agree it is probably less confusing to use `void **`. I've updated that paragraph

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself in a confusing way. I meant to say what you have edited into your answer, my english just let me down ._.

Comment: I'm unclear what you mean by "not a valid `IUnknown*` value". All COM interfaces must inherit from `IUnknown`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter In multiple inheritance the value of a pointer may differ from the value of a pointer to one of its bases. IOW `reinterpret_cast<Base *>(d)` is not the same as `dynamic_cast<Base *>(d)` .

Comment: I believe the rules of COM would prohibit this. *For any given object instance, a call to QueryInterface with IID_IUnknown must always return the same physical pointer value. This allows you to call QueryInterface on any two interfaces and compare the results to determine whether they point to the same instance of an object.*

Comment: @JonathanPotter A call to QueryInterface with `IID_IDispatch` can give a different value however

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now. Carry on! :)

Comment: @JonathanPotter the *implementation* class can use multiple inheritance, and if it implements multiple classes/interfaces derived from `IUnknown` then it has to decide which one's `IUnknown` to report for `QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown)`

Comment: *"In C++ programming you can (and perhaps should) use template wrapper classes that perform all the right type manipulations."* - Indeed, you should. The Windows SDK even provides one for you: [IID_PPV_ARGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args). In addition to handling the type manipulations, it addresses 2 more issues: `1` It ensures, that the pointee derives from (or is) an `IUnknown`. `2` It infers the `IID` from the interface pointer type to avoid any mismatches.

Comment: @IInspectable OK although that documentation is a bit fruity; it's actually a preprocessor macro that expands to two comma-separated arguments; not a function as shown in the doc

Comment: Correct, it's a macro (as the title suggests). It expands to a comma-separated list of arguments. The second argument is the return value of a function template instantiation, that performs the type manipulations. I'm not aware of any C++ feature that allows us to expand an expression to multiple tokens, so it needs to be a macro, unless you are willing to give up benefit `2`. Which really is the one that provides actual value.

Comment: Sorry, but this answer fails to nail down the actual reason. This isn't about convenience, or avoiding casts. The reason is, because you aren't *allowed* to cast between interface pointers in COM.

Comment: Besides, I believe that the comment on undefined behavior isn't true. The strict aliasing rule applies to *accessing* data. We cannot see that code, but it presumably writes through a properly typed pointer. Indeed, this is even more reason to use a `void**` instead of an `IUnknown**` in the `QueryInterface` signature, as the latter would indeed violate the strict aliasing rule. If the implementation is written in a programming language that has a strict aliasing rule.

Comment: @IInspectable reading and writing are both covered by the rule,  it is a violation to read or write an object via an lvalue of different type  (except for the listed exceptions in the rules)

Comment: Sure, but you *aren't* reading or writing through a pointer of a different type.

Comment: @IInspectable The QI function will modify a variable of type `IFoo *` via expression of type `void *`  (e.g. see this [sample implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/implementing-iunknown-in-c-plus-plus))

Comment: This is making assumptions about the implementation of QI. A conforming C++ implementation of QI could write `(IFoo*)*ppv = this;`, thereby assigning a value through a pointer that matches the dynamic type of the variable. Your proposed *"correct usage"* just broke a conforming implementation. I suppose the common term for this technique is *type erasure*. Are you suggesting, that type erasure through a `void*` cannot be made to work in C++?

Comment: @IInspectable well `::QueryInterface` can't do that if `IFoo` was a class defined by the user  since it doesn't know anything about that class.

Comment: QI knows *all* interface types it implements. If the user queries for an interface that a COM object doesn't implement, it is required to set `*ppv` to 0. Casting to `char*` and writing through this pointer is safe. This doesn't violate any more strict aliasing rules than - say - [std::qsort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/qsort).

Answer (score 0):

### Important take-away

This has nothing to do with legacy or convenience. The function signatures are the result of COM fundamentals to allow it to work. They are *required* to be typed the way they are. If you don't feel like reading through this answer, here are the important take-aways: The moral equivalent of a cast in C++ is a call to `QueryInterface` in COM. The only time you are allowed to use a C++ cast in COM is when implementing your COM object's `QueryInterface`.

### Details

Function signatures in COM that expect the address of a `void*` (as opposed to an `IUnknown*`) as an output parameter can return *any* interface type. If this were changed to an `IUnknown**` in a hypothetical implementation, it would make using COM either impractical, or right-out impossible.

Let's perform 2 thought experiments, starting with the one that would make COM impractical to use:

Let's assume that [CoCreateInstance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-cocreateinstance) were to return an `IUnknown*` instead of the real interface requested through a `void*`. In this case, a client would have to immediately call `QueryInterface` on the returned `IUnknown*` to receive the interface pointer they had asked for<sup>1</sup>. This isn't practical<sup>2</sup>.

This immediately leads into the impossible to solve experiment. Let's assume that `QueryInterface` returned an `IUnknown*`. To get to the real interface pointer, a client would need to call `QueryInterface`. But that only returns an `IUnknown*`! At that point the consumable interface surface of COM has collapsed into a single interface, `IUnknown`.

Whenever COM returns a pointer to an interface, it must return a pointer to the final type. The only programming language type that matches all interface pointers is indeed a `void*`.<sup>3</sup>
This should explain, why output parameters need to be typed `void**` rather than `IUnknown**`.

For [IObjectWithSite::SetSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ocidl/nf-ocidl-iobjectwithsite-setsite), on the other hand, the `IUnknown*` is an *input*. The interface still accepts *any* COM interface, but it needs to be passed as a pointer to the (identity-comparable) `IUnknown` interface.

---

<sup>1</sup> *COM does not mandate a particular object layout for implementations. Instead, it delegates requests for interface pointers to the respective `QueryInterface` implementations.*

<sup>2</sup> *Even when ignoring the immediate need to call `Release()` on the `IUnknown` to account for the bumped reference count as part of the `QI` call.*

<sup>3</sup> *From [The Component Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model):* "The only language requirement for COM is that code is generated in a language that can create structures of pointers and, either explicitly or implicitly, call functions through pointers." *There is deliberately no requirement, that interface inheritance be implemented using language-level constructs. Even when `IFoo` is required to implement `IUnknown`, there is no relationship between `IFoo*` and `IUnknown*` in a programming language like C.*